# Adjusting Views inside Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have placed the views of my view controllers inside a scroll view. But when i ran my app on iPhone 6Plus, my views doesn't fill the screen and i can see other view on the right. How can i fix this issue.

HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF THE PROBLEM

[image]

AND THIS IS MY CODE

```
contentView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentView.frame.size.width * 5, height: contentView.frame.size.height)


        rifleViewController.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.addSubview(rifleViewController.view)

        pistolViewController.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        pistolViewController.view.frame.origin.x = contentView.frame.size.width
        contentView.addSubview(pistolViewController.view)

        shotgunViewController.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        shotgunViewController.view.frame.origin.x = contentView.frame.size.width * 2
        contentView.addSubview(shotgunViewController.view)

        smgsViewController.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        smgsViewController.view.frame.origin.x = contentView.frame.size.width * 3
        contentView.addSubview(smgsViewController.view)

        sniperViewController.view.frame = contentView.bounds
        sniperViewController.view.frame.origin.x = contentView.frame.size.width * 4
        contentView.addSubview(sniperViewController.view)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `UICollectionView`? With the `UIViewControllers` added as child view controllers? It offers exactly the same functionality you are going for.

Comment: where are you setting the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. Turns out i forgot to add auto resizing to my scroll view. (stupid mistake) Thanks everyone for their answers!